# how to save csv into a txt, and search for records

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

Hello i'm new to python. 
I need to open a .csv archive(a list of ER admissions) read it and then save it into a .txt file. After that, I need to search for any record that includes any "death" and print it. I know how to open the csv and read it, but no clue how to save it into a txt.
And the second part is giving me some trouble

```
archivo = open('path/.csv', 'r+')
for linea in archivo.readlines():
        archivo.write(linea.replace(',', ' '))  #I should be saving into a .txt here, open the txt and then
        if "DEATH" in file:
           print line
```

I want the result to be the whole info(line)asociated with "DEATH" not just the word 'death'

Comment: Why save the data into a txt file? You could just as easily check for the presence of "DEATH" in the csv file itself, without having to transfer its contents into another file. Python doesn't treat csv files any differently from txt files. Opening one is the same as opening the other.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this..

```
f = open('yourTxtFile.txt','w')
with open('your_csv_file.csv', 'r+') as file_obj:
    for line in file_obj.readlines():
        f.write(line)
        if "death" in line.lower():
            print line
f.close()
```

if you open a file as your way you have to close file. so you can use with open statement to open a file where in you need not have to worry to close the file.

Comment: if this has solved your problem, please consider clicking the "tick" symbol on the left of my answer to mark it as accepted.